# non-unique #_ajax_nonce id in browser console

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I have added multiple custom fields through a meta-box, and  i have used `wp_nonce_field` function that generates a nonce for each field and every thing is working for This meta box, but also WP renders those custom fields below the meta box, but without unique nonces, which displays a console error of non unique nonce id for those fields. So now i have my meta-box with it's fields and again those fields are rendered by WordPress down with same values under custom fields section, how to get rid of this or fix this problem.

Here is how i added fields..
Actually i have a class that adds metabox with the following method

```
/**
 * Add metaboxes.
 */
public function add_meta_box(){
        if( is_array( $this->post_type ) ){

            foreach ( $this->post_type as $post_type ) {
                add_meta_box( $this->id, $this->label, array( $this, 'meta_fields_callback' ), $post_type, $this->context, $this->priority );
            }

        }else{

            add_meta_box( $this->id, $this->label, array( $this, 'meta_fields_callback' ), $this->post_type, $this->context, $this->priority );

        }
    }
```

which uses the callable `meta_fields_callback`

```
/**
 * Render metabox' fields.
 */
public function meta_fields_callback(){
        global $post;

        //Array of inputs that have same HTML markup
        $mixed_types = ['text','number','email', 'password','url'];

        //Loop through inputs to render
        foreach($this->fields as $field){

            $render_field = new ANONY_Input_Field($field, 'meta', $post->ID);

            $render_field->field_init();

            if(isset($field['scripts']) && !empty($field['scripts'])){

                foreach($field['scripts'] as $script){

                    $deps = (isset($script['dependancies']) && !empty($script['dependancies'])) ? $script['dependancies'] : [];

                    $deps[] = 'anony-metaboxs';

                    if(isset($script['file_name'])){

                        $url = ANONY_MB_URI. 'assets/js/'.$script['file_name'].'.js';

                    }elseif(isset($script['url'])){

                        $url = $script['url'];
                    }

                    wp_enqueue_script($script['handle'], $url, $deps, false, true);
                }
            }



        }
        wp_referer_field();
    }
```

The callable will render a field depending on a method of name `field_init()` which is defined in a separate class on name `ANONY_Input_Field` the `field_init` is:

```
/**
 * Initialize options field
 */
public function field_init(){

        if(!is_null($this->field_class) && class_exists($this->field_class))
        {

            $field_class = $this->field_class;

            $field = new $field_class($this);

            if($this->context == 'meta'){
                wp_nonce_field( $this->field['id'].'_action', $this->field['id'].'_nonce', false );
            }
            $field->render();


        }
    }
```

In this method i use `wp_nonce_field` function to generate the nonce for each field.

All theses are working as expected but the problem lies in fields that are rendered automatically in custom fields section into edit post screen.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: it is complicated but I will try to summerize

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Also, you should only need to use just one nonce for a metabox (which I assume is intended for a certain action) and not one for every single field in that metabox.

Comment: Good point, I think you are right about using one nonce, but for the main problem, I have activated a premium theme that has metaboxes register l, and also the same problem.. the automatically rendered custom fields by wordpress doesn't have unique IDs

Comment: I see now what you mean. The standard custom fields editor uses `_ajax_nonce` as the nonce field's `name` and `wp_nonce_field()` is automatically setting the field's `id` attribute to the field name, which causes the issues for repeatable fields like the ones in the standard custom fields editor. So I don't see a way to fix that using filter hook, but you could probably just ignore the console error for now..